# Create new column with fuzzy-score across two string columns in the same dataframe

Tags: dataframe, apache-spark, pyspark, matching, fuzzywuzzy

I'm trying to calculate a fuzzy score (preferable partial_ratio score) across two columns in the same dataframe.

```
| column1 | column2|
| -------- | -------------- |
| emmett holt| holt
| greenwald| christopher
```

It would need to look something like this:

```
| column1 | column2|partial_ratio|
| -------- | -------------- |-----------|
| emmett holt| holt|100|
| greenwald| christopher|22|
|schaefer|schaefer|100|
```

With the help of another question on this website, I worked towards the following code:

```
compare=pd.MultiIndex.from_product([ dataframe['column1'],dataframe ['column2'] ]).to_series()

def metrics (tup):
   return pd.Series([fuzz.partial_ratio(*tup)], ['partial_ratio'])

df['partial_ratio'] = df.apply(lambda x: fuzz.partial_ratio(x['original_title'], x['title']), axis=1)
```

But the problem already starts with the first line of the code that returns the following error notification:

> Cannot convert column into bool: please use '&' for 'and', '|' for 'or', '~' for 'not' when building DataFrame boolean expressions.

You can say I'm kind of stuck here so any advice on this is appreciated!

Comment: how does `schaefer` appear?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a UDF to use fuzzywuzzy:

```
from fuzzywuzzy import fuzz
import pyspark.sql.functions as F

@F.udf
def fuzzyudf(original_title, title):
    return fuzz.partial_ratio(original_title, title)

df2 = df.withColumn('partial_ratio', fuzzyudf('column1', 'column2'))
df2.show()

+-----------+-----------+-------------+
|    column1|    column2|partial_ratio|
+-----------+-----------+-------------+
|emmett holt|       holt|          100|
|  greenwald|christopher|           22|
+-----------+-----------+-------------+
```